# Max-norm projection of a Hermitian matrix onto the set of positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, matrices, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

For a given Hermitian matrix $A$ (i.e. complex matrix with $A_{ij}^{\ast}=A_{ji}$) find its max-norm projection onto the set of complex positive semi-definite matrices:

$$\Pi(A)=\mathrm{argmin}_{M\succeq0}\|A-M\|_{\infty}.$$

Here $\|A\|_{\infty}=\mathrm{max}_{ij}|A_{ij}|$ is the entry-wise max-norm. This problem has exact solution for the Frobenius and spectral matrix norm (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2436094/find-the-matrix-projection-of-a-symmetric-matrix-onto-the-set-of-symmetric-posit)). Is there a closed-form solution for the max-norm? Is there an efficient algorithm to calculate the projection and what is the computational cost (for $n\times n$ complex matrix)?

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer regarding an algorithm to find projection, not a closed form.

The problem is of the following convex SDP:
$$
\min_{t,M} ~~~~~~~t\\
\mbox{subject to}\\
\hspace{5cm} |A_{i,j}-M_{i,j}|\leq t, ~\forall ~i,j\\
\hspace{3cm}M\succeq 0.
$$
This can be solved using CVXPY (or a software alike). You might want to check Boyd's Convex Optimization for the exact details of the  computational complexity of interior point methods.